# how to use singe processor in nifi for connecting multiple table at a time

Tags: database, datatables, apache-nifi, processor, apache-nifi-toolkit

I want to fetch multiple tables from MySQL and it should take only one processor in apache nifi.. is there any specific way to do it or there is no other way and we have to use one processor for one table every time?

i tired doing it with executeSql but I am able to put one table at a time

Comment: Could you please provide further information on the tables structure, are you trying to use a UNION to fetch data from multiple tables. What are you trying to do further down the line with the tables process them separately. This would help us the community to provide a better response.